# MPI Seg. fault when using send/recv with Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix, mpi, allocation

I'm dealing with dynamic allocated matrices, and need to send/recv them from a process to another.
I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but sometimes, with small matrices, it works; but when I increase their dimensions, it gets this error:

```
[caio-A790GXM-AD3:03111] *** Process received signal ***
[caio-A790GXM-AD3:03111] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[caio-A790GXM-AD3:03111] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[caio-A790GXM-AD3:03111] Failing at address: (nil)
```

Here is the basic part where I think the error might be:

```
float **alocarMatriz(int linhas, int colunas) {
    int i;
    float *dado = (float *)calloc(linhas*colunas,sizeof(float));
    float **array = (float **)calloc(linhas,sizeof(float*));
    for(i = 0; i < linhas; i++) 
        array[i] = &(dado[colunas*i]);
    return array;
};

if(taskid == MASTER) {
    float **matriz;
    matriz = alocarMatriz(numLin,numCol);
    MPI_Send(&matriz[0][0], colunasAVT*colunasDAT, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if(taskid > MASTER) {
    float **matriz;
    matriz = alocarMatriz(numLin,numCol);
    MPI_Recv(&matriz[0][0], colunasAVT*colunasDAT, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

---

EDIT:

Fixed the index of Recv, also tried to run the same program, but with fixed size arrays instead of calloc'd. No success anyway, it still points segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the pointer to the array correct for Send, but not for Recv.  Recv, too, should be `MPI_Recv(&(matriz[0][0]), ...` (or, equivalently, `MPI_Recv(matriz[0], ...`).

Comment: Nice pointed! But still, no success. Can I directly contact you and send you the code? I saw you answer another thread and thought about it before, but I didn't want to bother. Now that you answered mine, I feel more comfortable asking.

Comment: One of the nice features of SO is that other people with the same problem later can search, find this question and find the solutions here.  So let's keep the discussion on the page.    Can you post the relevant parts of the code in your question, or elswhere and post a link there?

Comment: I think it's solved now, I tested so many things that I don't know exactly what was happening. But a guy helped me out and it works now! He pointed that I was sending Float and using MPI_DOUBLE as parameter... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return values of `calloc`.  Most likely it returns `NULL`, and then you access the memory and cause a seg fault.

Comment: What would be the proper way to check?
I tried
     if(array==NULL) printf("error!\n");
it gets no error this way...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like another instance of MPI and arrays-of-arrays.

One way to allocate an N by M matrix is to allocate `N * M * sizeof(type)` bytes. Since you allocate the columns of an array, then allocate the container for those arrays, don't you have to be more sophisticated in how you describe this memory to MPI?

I think, much like how you allocated in the first place, you will have to build up an MPI type.